# Python socket accept() not working when called from a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tcp

The connection is happening during the first execution of method in the following code , but from the second time execution of the function within the thread , the accept() function is not accepting any functoin , it just stays at the prompt and does nothing even if i connect from other local devices . Any help would be really helpfull. Here is the code. I am really new to threading. So please correct my mistakes and give full explaination for any errors in my code.

```
def serverwaiter():
    myip = "192.168.1.2";
    port = 6027;
    s = socket.socket();
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
    s.bind((myip, 6027));
    s.listen(10);
    print("My ip  :- {}".format(myip)) ;
    cobj , addr = s.accept() ;
    mythread = threading.Thread(target = serverwaiter, name = "TCP connection waiter {}".format(threading.active_count()-1))
    threads.append((cobj,addr)) ;
    mythread.start() ;
    print("Connected to {}".format(addr[0])) ;
    data = cobj.recv(1024) ;
    print("Host {} sent data = {}".format(addr, data));

    while(len(data)!=0):
        print("Waiting for Data from {}".format(addr[0])) ;
        data = cobj.recv(1024) ;
        data = data.decode() ;
        print("Host {} sent data = {}".format(addr ,data)) ;

serverwaiter() ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spin off threads just for servicing the client.  Now you are starting another server each time a client connects.  Try this:

```
import socket
import threading

def serverwaiter():
    port = 6027
    s = socket.socket()
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
    s.bind(('',6027))
    s.listen(10)
    while True:
        cobj,addr = s.accept()
        mythread = threading.Thread(target=client,name='TCP client {}'.format(threading.active_count()-1),args=(cobj,addr))
        mythread.daemon = True # So client threads die on main thread exit.
        mythread.start()

def client(cobj,addr):
    print('Connected to',addr)
    while True:
        data = cobj.recv(1024)
        if not data: break
        print('Host {} sent data = {}'.format(addr,data.decode()))
    cobj.close()

serverwaiter()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run the thread's target within a while-true loop. I also suggest you organize your code for better understanding.

```
def mythread():
        while True:
               accept()
```

Remember to always pass the variables as arguments so nothing is left behind